# How to push app in background and launch from same screen in Appium with selenium Put app in background. Open the app from same screen

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-android

How to push app in background and launch from same screen in Appium with selenium

Press home button from some specific screen. Put app in background. Open the app from same screen after some time interval

Here I am able to set the app in background by below code but not finding the way to get the app in foreground with last visited page, currently with below code approaches, the app is getting relaunched with initial login screen. Can any one please help in same.

Code1:

```
driver.runAppInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(15));
2.Activity activity = new Activity(“com.gisteam.rjiomaps.projectresq”, “com.gisteam.rjiomaps.projectresq.main.MapFragmentActivity”);//activity name is as per the last visited page
3.activity.setStopApp(false);
((AndroidDriver) driver).startActivity(activity);
```

Code2

```
1.driver.runAppInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(15));
2.((AndroidDriver) driver).currentActivity();
```

Comment: To bring it to foreground `driver.activateApp("app package name");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to push app in background and launch from same screen in Appium with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191358/how-to-push-app-in-background-and-launch-from-same-screen-in-appium-with-seleniu)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! But I have tried all the way shared in above link with activate app command also but with these application is getting relaunch instead of the last opened page.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the application and navigate to desired screen on the app, minimize app by using adb keycode for home button 
   **adb shell input keyevent 3**
2. Open application again without installing by using adb command to launch the activity like below example

**adb shell am start -n com.example.package(Put your package name here)/.MainActivity (Activity to be launched )**